# Connect a .NET Core app with EF to a remote Postgresql Database in a VPS

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, vps

I have been trying to connect to a staging database, located on a VPS hosted by OVH.

I followed some instructions that I found on the internet but I keep having this exception when I start the application (The StartUp makes some DB queries)

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occured. (An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.)
---> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
---> Npgsl.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting
---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
```

I tried to change the DB config on the remote server :

- changed the "listen_adresses" from 'localhost' to '*' in the postgresl.conf file
- add a line to the end of the file pg_hba.conf : host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
- Changed the connection string : Host=HOST_ADDRESS;Port=HOST_PORT;Username=myusername;Password=mypassword;Database=mydatabasename;

It might on this that I have an issue. I'm not sure of what I should put for Host and Port.

I can connect to the remote database locally on PgAdmin4 thanks Putty using SSH Tunnel. A fictive port have been created on 5434 that forwards to the 5432 on the remote server. I tried to use both in the port, without success.
For the HOST_ADDRESS, I use the same than the one set in Putty.

Comment: Can you connect to the database at all? EF Core isn't a database driver. If you can connect to the remote database using eg pgAdmin, you can connect with EF Core.

Comment: [You should not post errors as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7450780)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @DenisMicheal.k , I changed it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I can connect. Yes indeed, actually it was quite easy. It's just that I took time to find the solution, I keep the post so others that have the same situation loose less time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer.

Since I'm connected to the VPS through Putty, I just had to add the Port I used (5434), keep 'localhost' in Host, and change the username/password.

It's all working now :)